# Can i get a listid (guid) value of a current list in SharePoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list

Is it possible to get the list guid value of a current list?
I want to be able to use this in url i'm concatenating in the workflow.
I don't want to hardcode it.
Any tips would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which spd workflow(2010 or 2013) are you using?

Comment: currently using SP2010. Does this make any difference?

Comment: Yes, It will, In Spd 2013 we can get direct current List ID and In Spd 2010 we have to get from Workflow Status URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SPD workflow 2013 we can get current List Id (GUID) directly from `Workflow Context` -> `List ID`. As you can see below Image.
[image]

In SPD workflow 2010 we can get current List Id (GUID) from `Workflow Context` -> `Workflow Status URL` after performing some string operation. As you can see below Image.
[image]

Comment: Great thanks worked well. Can i also  get the current list name

Comment: Great, Welcome :)