# 2010 Workflow: Copy Item (Document) from another list to current list (current item's list)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, document-library, copy-item

I have a workflow which starts by copying some documents into a drafts folder. The thing is, after the workflow is finished the copied document needs to be copied back into the list(folder) from which it came. I want the copy to replace the original in the list. How can I specify this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot, there is an option to overwrite. It is set to "No". Please try changing that to "Yes".

If the above does not help. Check under what account, the workflow is running. That account should have "contribute" permission on the library where it is trying to replace the documents .

Edit : to get the list id of the list where the workflow is running:
we can get current List Id (GUID) from Workflow Context -> Workflow Status URL after performing some string operation. Have a look at the answers to the following question:

[Can i get a listid (guid) value of a current list in SharePoint designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251730/can-i-get-a-listid-guid-value-of-a-current-list-in-sharepoint-designer)

Comment: you misunderstand my question: I need to get information for "tolistid"

Comment: You need to get information for "tolistid" means? Do you need to figure out which id to choose ? i.e you need to find the id of the original list from where the document came?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: See if my edit to the answer helps you.

Comment: Looks like I am able to get the listID but i am unable to insert that ID into the copy file action in the workflow

Answer (score 0):

In the action property, set overwrite as yes.

[image]

Comment: you misunderstand my question: I need to get information for "tolistid"